Adding faces to a mesh
I am trying to create a mesh (.stl file) that follows a bezier curve. I have succesfully created the side face but I have trouble creating the top and bottom faces. The problem is that the bezier curve is quite complex (the shape can be concave or convex) and the faces i have managed to create don't follow the curve exactly (I will add a picture). Is there a way to make the top and bottom faces follow the curve exactly and also fill the shape (i don't want it to be hollow).
This is the code I use to create the mesh.
import numpy as np
import trimesh
import shape
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

def create_mesh(x, y, z_bottom, z_top):
    """ Create a mesh from the bezier curve points """
    # Create vertices for the bottom and top surfaces
    vertices = np.vstack((np.column_stack((x, y, z_bottom)), np.column_stack((x, y, z_top))))
    num_points = len(x)

    # Create faces
    faces = []
    
    for i in range(num_points - 1):
        # Side face
        faces.append([i, i + 1, num_points + i + 1])
        faces.append([i, num_points + i + 1, num_points + i])

    # Closing the side face
    faces.append([num_points - 1, 0, num_points])
    faces.append([num_points - 1, num_points, num_points + (num_points - 1)])

    # Top face
    top_vertices = np.column_stack((x, y, z_top))
    top = Delaunay(top_vertices[:, :2])
    top_faces = top.simplices + num_points

    # Bottom face
    bottom_vertices = np.column_stack((x, y, z_bottom))
    bottom = Delaunay(bottom_vertices[:, :2])
    bottom_faces = bottom.simplices
    
    # Combine faces
    faces = np.array(faces + top_faces.tolist() + bottom_faces.tolist())
    
    # Create the mesh
    mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices=vertices, faces=faces)

    return mesh

And this is the shape.py code i use to get the curve.
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bernstein = lambda n, k, t: binom(n,k)* t**k * (1.-t)**(n-k)

def bezier(points, num=200):
    N = len(points)
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=num)
    curve = np.zeros((num, 2))
    for i in range(N):
        curve += np.outer(bernstein(N - 1, i, t), points[i])
    return curve

class Segment():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, angle1, angle2, **kw):
        self.p1 = p1; self.p2 = p2
        self.angle1 = angle1; self.angle2 = angle2
        self.numpoints = kw.get("numpoints", 100)
        r = kw.get("r", 0.3)
        d = np.sqrt(np.sum((self.p2-self.p1)**2))
        self.r = r*d
        self.p = np.zeros((4,2))
        self.p[0,:] = self.p1[:]
        self.p[3,:] = self.p2[:]
        self.calc_intermediate_points(self.r)

    def calc_intermediate_points(self,r):
        self.p[1,:] = self.p1 + np.array([self.r*np.cos(self.angle1),
                                    self.r*np.sin(self.angle1)])
        self.p[2,:] = self.p2 + np.array([self.r*np.cos(self.angle2+np.pi),
                                    self.r*np.sin(self.angle2+np.pi)])
        self.curve = bezier(self.p,self.numpoints)


def get_curve(points, **kw):
    segments = []
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        seg = Segment(points[i,:2], points[i+1,:2], points[i,2],points[i+1,2],**kw)
        segments.append(seg)
    curve = np.concatenate([s.curve[:-1] for s in segments])
    # curve = curve[::-1]
    return segments, curve

def ccw_sort(p):
    d = p-np.mean(p,axis=0)
    s = np.arctan2(d[:,0], d[:,1])
    return p[np.argsort(s),:]

def get_bezier_curve(rad=0.2, edgy=0, height=1.0):
    """ Given an array of points *a*, create a 3D curve through those points.
    *rad* controls the distance of control points.
    *edgy* controls how "edgy" the curve is.
    *height* is the fixed height to extend in the z direction."""
    
    a = get_random_points(n=7, scale=1)
    p = np.arctan(edgy) / np.pi + 0.5
    a = ccw_sort(a)
    a = np.append(a, np.atleast_2d(a[0, :]), axis=0)
    d = np.diff(a, axis=0)
    ang = np.arctan2(d[:, 1], d[:, 0])
    f = lambda ang: (ang >= 0) * ang + (ang < 0) * (ang + 2 * np.pi)
    ang = f(ang)
    ang1 = ang
    ang2 = np.roll(ang, 1)
    ang = p * ang1 + (1 - p) * ang2 + (np.abs(ang2 - ang1) > np.pi) * np.pi
    ang = np.append(ang, [ang[0]])
    a = np.append(a, np.atleast_2d(ang).T, axis=1)

    # Generate 2D curve
    s, c = get_curve(a, r=rad, method="var")
    x, y = c.T

    # Create 3D vertices by extending in the z direction
    z = np.zeros_like(x)
    z_top = np.full_like(x, height)

    # Combine into a 3D array
    return x, y, z, z_top, a


def get_random_points(n=5, scale=0.8, mindst=None, rec=0):
    """ create n random points in the unit square, which are *mindst*
    apart, then scale them."""
    mindst = mindst or .7/n
    a = np.random.rand(n,2)
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(ccw_sort(a), axis=0), axis=1)**2)
    if np.all(d >= mindst) or rec>=200:
        return a*scale
    else:
        return get_random_points(n=n, scale=scale, mindst=mindst, rec=rec+1)


def get_curvature(x, y=None, error=0.1):
    if y is None:
        x, y = x.real, x.imag

    t = np.arange(x.shape[0])
    std = error * np.ones_like(x)

    fx = UnivariateSpline(t, x, k=4, w=1 / np.sqrt(std))
    fy = UnivariateSpline(t, y, k=4, w=1 / np.sqrt(std))

    xˈ = fx.derivative(1)(t)
    xˈˈ = fx.derivative(2)(t)
    yˈ = fy.derivative(1)(t)
    yˈˈ = fy.derivative(2)(t)
    curvature = (xˈ* yˈˈ - yˈ* xˈˈ) / np.power(xˈ** 2 + yˈ** 2, 3 / 2)
    return curvature

This is an example of what i get (just adding the top and bottom faces and not filling the object). As you can see the top and bottom faces don't match exactly.


I believe your problem is that you take all the simplices of the Delaunay triangulation, which by definition cover all the convex hull of the points. Since your curve is not convex, you get at the top and bottom faces, triangles that are outside the curve.
I suggest you check this by viewing the mesh in wireframe (so you can see the triangles you got).
If your sample of the Bezier curve is dense enough then the Delaunay triangulation will contain all the edges of the Bezier polygon (i.e., all Delaunay triangles will either be totally inside or totally outside of the polygon).
Then all you need to do is remove the simplices that are totally outside the polygon.
This can be done by testing if the mean point of the triangle (p1+p2+p3) / 3 is outside the polygon. This point in polygon test can be implemented in several ways. See for example the implemented function points_in_polygon in my previous answer here. Or this answer that uses the Shapely library.
